# Google log in API to recover the password set by the user within my app

Tags: android, google-api

If anyone has used hexlock, if you forget the password it opens a Google log in for the current account associated with your device (doesn't offer to choose from a bunch of accounts you have) and prompts you to enter the password of that account in order to reset you Hexlock password. What API are they using?

[image: Log in]

Answer (score 0):

Found it can be achieved using [confirmCredentials(Account, Bundle, Activity, AccountManagerCallback, Handler)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#confirmCredentials(android.accounts.Account,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler)) of the [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) class. First filter the account type as "com.google" and then confirm credentials of that account.